# MySql select showing total grouped by condition

Tags: mysql, select

I have this table:

```
SALESMAN |   INVOICE     |   VALUE   
1        |   7470        |   10       
1        |   7471        |   20       
1        |   7472        |   30     
2        |   7473        |   40       
2        |   7474        |   50
```

I want a query in order to get this result:

```
SALESMAN |   INVOICE     |   VALUE   |  TOTAL_VALUE  | TOTAL_ITEMS
1        |   7470        |   10      |  40           | 3
1        |   7471        |   20      |  40           | 3
1        |   7472        |   10      |  40           | 3
2        |   7473        |   40      |  90           | 2
2        |   7474        |   50      |  90           | 2
```

`TOTAL_VALUE` is the sum of all `VALUE` for the same `SALESMAN`. 
`TOTAL_ITEMS` is the amount of rows with the same `SALESMAN`.

Is possible to achieve this in MySql?

Comment: Both, Rahul and Gouda answers have worked for me, I have tried with some data in MySql Workbench client and it shows the same time. Now the question is: what of both methods is more efficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT s.SALESMAN, s.INVOICE, s.VALUE,
xx.TOTAL_VALUE, xx.TOTAL_ITEMS
FROM sales s JOIN
(SELECT SALESMAN,
    SUM(VALUE) AS TOTAL_VALUE,
    COUNT(value) AS TOTAL_ITEMS
    FROM sales
    GROUP BY SALESMAN) xx ON S.SALESMAN = xx.SALESMAN;
```

Answer (score 1):

this query:

```
SELECT SALESMAN, INVOICE , VALUE,  
(select sum(VALUE) FROM your_table t1 where t1.SALESMAN = your_table.SALESMAN) 
AS TOTAL_VALUE, 
(select count(VALUE) FROM your_table t2 where t2.SALESMAN = your_table.SALESMAN) 
AS TOTAL_ITEMS 
from your_table
```

Comment: Throwing code at readers without an explanation isn't very helpful. Please explain what specific issue had to be addressed, and how this SQL statement solves it.

Comment: Could you explain how/why your code works? That'll enable the OP and others to understand and apply your methods (where applicable) elsewhere. Code-only answers are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148272/284827) and liable to be deleted. — [During review](http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/10940464)